# PowerBI Date Filter for all pages

Tags: powerbi

I would like to create a date filter for all pages in my report.

I've tried using a date slicer, however, it defaults to "on this visual".

Answer (score 0):

try using the following formula to create a table:

```
Calendario = CALENDAR(DATE(2018,01,01),DATE(2019,12,31))

--The first date would be the lower bound and the second one the upper bound.
```

Then procede to link every table date to this specific table. If you have a Date variable for each one table, it will not filter all the data.

Also, you can try going to View and selecting Sync Slicers. Another way of doing this is copy and pasting the filter in another page. It will show a dialog box that will ask if you want to sync all the slicers.